# How to add js file to admin category edit via xml?

Tags: module, adminhtml, xml

I have created a module and I am trying to include a custom js file into the category edit page.

In my `config.xml` file I have:

```
<config>
    ...
    <adminhtml>
        <layout>
            <updates>
                <my_module>
                    <file>my_module.xml</file>
                </my_module>
            </updates>
        </layout>
    </adminhtml>
</config>
```

And in my `app/design/adminhtml/default/default/layout/my_module.xml` file I have:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout>
    <adminhtml_catalog_category_edit>
        <reference name="head">
            <action method="addJs"><script>my_js_file.js</script></action>
        </reference>
    </adminhtml_catalog_category_edit>
</layout>
```

According to all references, this *should* work, but when I view the source of the category edit page, I do not see it being included in the head.

What am I doing wrong? Why is my file not being included?

Comment: Is your file located under `/js/my_js_file.js` ?

Comment: @DigitalPianism Yes...

Comment: Try with `<layout version="0.1.0">` instead of `<layout>`

Answer (score 0):

I'm an idiot. I had added the path in my config.xml, but had added the my_module.xml in the right path but in the wrong project >.< The above code does work. Thanks anyway.